# Something weird is happening. Everytime I start Jenkins on my laptop, the Java 8 JDK folder in my laptop vanishes. Is that just me?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I installed Jenkins and ran builds for the selenium suite that I am building. I initiated it via cli and run multiple jobs and they all seem to run fine but after that I cant find the Java 8 JDK in the program files. This happened once before and i had to reinstall Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was installing Java automatically for the Jenkins run and this was overwriting the installation